# IBM/Lenovo X61 Tablet PC - cleaning a dried water patch under the wacom display surface

Tags: lcd, lenovo-laptop, tablet-pc

Got myself a used Lenovo X61 tablet PC (a notebook with Wacom pen responsive display) - the price was super cheap, and as per the phrase of "*you get what you pay for*", I got the notebook in a surprisingly bad shape.

The thing is, **the notebook has some horrible stains on the underneath of the display** - the stains are so bad that they make the color white in the affected areas appear as yellow, or even gray-ish. I want to clean these stains.
These stains (two gigantic stains that block out about one third of the display) seem like dried rust water patches ... or something (never seen anything like that ... and god knows what the previous owner did with the notebook).

Anyway, the notebook has three display layers:

1. (on the outside): the wacom matrix (this registers the movement of the Wacom pen)
2. (in the middle): a plexiglass
3. (on the inside)? the LCD itself

According to [this Vimeo guide](http://vimeo.com/3933798), I managed to get to about 8:45 (opening up the display and separating the Wacom matrix + plexiglass from the LCD panel underneath).
To my dismay, the awful stain is not in between of the plexiglass <-> LCD area; it is stuck between the plexiglass and the Wacom matrix.

The thing is, the Wacom matrix seems to be rather well glued to the plexiglass ... and here I'm not that sure about prying those two parts apart, in fear of breaking it.

Any advice?